# How do I connect to an "internal" Microsoft Exchange Server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, outlook-web-access

I'm able to login to Outlook Web Access portal on my college's website from home. However, I would like to be able to sync this to my iPad or preferably to my Gmail account.

Under the "About" section in the "Office Outlook Web Access" is:

```
Mailbox owner:  xxxxxxx xxxxx [xxx@xxxxxxx]
User-Agent: 
Outlook Web Access experience:  Basic
Exchange mailbox address:   /o=Exchange Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (xxxxxxxxxx)/cn=Recipients/cn=xxxxx
Outlook Web Access host address:    https://xxxxxxxx/owa
Outlook Web Access version: 8.1.436.0
Outlook Web Access host name:   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Client Access server name:  xxx-exc-001.xxxnet.internal
Mailbox server name:    xxx-exc-001.xxxnet.internal
Mailbox server Microsoft Exchange version:  8.1.240.0
Authentication type associated with this Outlook Web Access session:    Basic
Public logon:   Yes
```

I'm a bit confused by `xxx-exc-001.xxxnet.internal` since it says "internal" but obviously I'm able to access it from home.

Comment: Depending on the configuration of the network it might not be possible.  You can try the ip address.  Based on the information provided this is unlikely.  I would contact your school's IT department and request assistance since they have access to the information you would need.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the Outlook Web Access server (`https://xxxxxxxx/owa`) from home.

The names ending in `.internal` are servers inside the college's network. That is, they are likely only accessible inside the firewall, whereas the OWA server is accessible from outside the firewall. They do not need to be exposed to the internet in order for OWA to work.  You communicate with the OWA server, and it communicates with those "internal" servers on your behalf.

To sync with a mobile device, your Exchange mailbox needs the **Exchange ActiveSync** feature enabled, if it's not already. Your e-mail administrator would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the web address `https://xxxxxxxx/owa`
the iPad setup uses that address, with your username and password.